# Multiple writes for android sqlite3

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How can we write simultaneously multiple time in sqlite3 database in android
if I am performing a database operation from an activity and at same time if my android service starts (Which also perform database insertion) then how to handler the database operation.

as android developer website says 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLockingEnabled%28boolean%29

that SetLocakingEnabled " **method is deprecated**". 
So how we can access multiple write(insertion) operation in Database.

I also referred to the documentation of sqlite for locking 
http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

please provide any example for the same .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by multiple write access.  But what you probably want to do is lock the database with a transaction and perform your inserts, then when complete end the transaction.

```
//in your database access class...assuming you have a list of objects to insert

public function void multiple_write(ArrayList<Object> list) {
  //this locks the database
  db.beginTransaction();
  for (Object obj : list) {
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, getContentValues(obj));
  }

  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
  //this completes your transaction
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: multiple writes means i can write into the data base file from an activity and a service also at the same time .

Comment: That situation suggests you should be using a content provider to provide the access for both usages (Activity & Service).